# How to convert from object space to clip space

Tags: shaders, hlsl, unity-urp

I want to animate foliage with vertex animation but I have wrong output because I can't correctrly transform from object space to clip space, and my foliage goes off the model. How Can I convert in corrent way the space?

```
fragmentInput vertexProgram(vertexInput data)
{
    UNITY_SETUP_INSTANCE_ID(data);

    fragmentInput output;
    float3 positionWS = TransformObjectToWorld(data.positionOS);
    output.positionCS = TransformWorldToHClip(positionWS);
    output.positionWSAndFog = float4(positionWS, ComputeFogFactor(output.positionCS.z));

    VertexNormalInputs normalInput = GetVertexNormalInputs(data.normalOS, data.tangentOS);
    output.normalWS = normalInput.normalWS;
    output.tangentWS = normalInput.tangentWS;
    output.bitangentWS = normalInput.bitangentWS;

    output.uv = TRANSFORM_TEX(data.uv, _BaseColor);

    output.viewDirectionWS = GetWorldSpaceViewDir(positionWS);

#ifdef _MAIN_LIGHT_SHADOWS
    output.shadowCoord = TransformWorldToShadowCoord(positionWS);
#endif

    OUTPUT_LIGHTMAP_UV(input.staticLightmapUV, unity_LightmapST, output.staticLightmapUV);
    OUTPUT_SH(output.normalWS, output.vertexSH);
    
    // I'm starting my animation from here
    float4 worldPos = mul(data.positionOS, unity_ObjectToWorld);
    float2 samplePos = worldPos.xz / _WorldSize.xz;
    samplePos += _Time.x * _WindSpeed.xy;
    float windSample = tex2Dlod(_WindTex, float4(samplePos, 0, 0));

    output.positionCS.x += sin(_WaveSpeed * windSample) * _WaveAmp;
    output.positionCS.z += cos(_WaveSpeed * windSample) * _WaveAmp;

    // then I sholud somehow convert to clip space if im not wrong
    return output;
}
```

Here what I've got:
[image]

Comment: It looks to me like you have the correct function to use already demonstrated at the top of this code: `TransformWorldToHClip(positionWS);` [You can find its source code here](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/Graphics/blob/master/Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.core/ShaderLibrary/SpaceTransforms.hlsl). How have you tried using this so far and where did things go wrong?

Comment: @DMGregory I used it with cg transform function before and it was ok, but now with hlsl it doesn't work

Comment: What exact code did you write using this function, and in what way did the results differ from what you wanted?

Comment: @DMGregory I Finally resolved it. The value for wave amplitude was too high, it affect on the position.

Comment: @DMGregory I remember I did it already, but im too tired, to remember this right now. So my mistake

Answer (score 0):

_WaveAmp value was too high and affect possition of vertecies. Around 0.08 is ok

```
    output.positionCS.x += sin(_WaveSpeed * windSample) * _WaveAmp;
    output.positionCS.z += cos(_WaveSpeed * windSample) * _WaveAmp;
```

Comment: You're modifying the position directly in homogeneous clip space. That will make your animation view dependent, which may not be what you want.

Comment: @DMGregory Yes, I get it. I'm only studying all that stuff and don't know any other war right now. Thanks for the information

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like what you want is something like this. Start with the beginning of the shader until it computes the position in world space:

```
fragmentInput vertexProgram(vertexInput data)
{
    UNITY_SETUP_INSTANCE_ID(data);

    fragmentInput output;
    float3 positionWS = TransformObjectToWorld(data.positionOS);
```

Now add your code that modifies the world space position. You don't need your line `float4 worldPos = ...` since `positionWS` already contains the world space position:

```
    float2 samplePos = positionWS.xz / _WorldSize.xz;
    samplePos += _Time.x * _WindSpeed.xy;
    float windSample = tex2Dlod(_WindTex, float4(samplePos, 0, 0));

    positionWS.x += sin(_WaveSpeed * windSample) * _WaveAmp;
    positionWS.z += cos(_WaveSpeed * windSample) * _WaveAmp;
```

Now you can continue with the rest of the shader, that computes the clip space position from the world space position:

```
    output.positionCS = TransformWorldToHClip(positionWS);
    output.positionWSAndFog = float4(positionWS, ComputeFogFactor(output.positionCS.z));

    VertexNormalInputs normalInput = GetVertexNormalInputs(data.normalOS, data.tangentOS);
    output.normalWS = normalInput.normalWS;
    output.tangentWS = normalInput.tangentWS;
    output.bitangentWS = normalInput.bitangentWS;

    output.uv = TRANSFORM_TEX(data.uv, _BaseColor);

    output.viewDirectionWS = GetWorldSpaceViewDir(positionWS);

#ifdef _MAIN_LIGHT_SHADOWS
    output.shadowCoord = TransformWorldToShadowCoord(positionWS);
#endif

    OUTPUT_LIGHTMAP_UV(input.staticLightmapUV, unity_LightmapST, output.staticLightmapUV);
    OUTPUT_SH(output.normalWS, output.vertexSH);
    
    return output;
}
```

Doing it this way, your wind displacement also affects the shadow.

Comment: Thanks for help